# why is my regular expression greedy?

Tags: java, regex

1. alsjasdfad 
   asdfasfasfa

2.asdfasdfasdf

3.

2.

Above is the string I am trying to match with this regex - **\n1.(.+)\n2.**
So, what I am trying to do is match 1. and the next 2. But my regex still matches the last 2. I am using 'single line' modifier, i.e, dot matches all on this regex. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `(.+)` to `(.+?)`, this is covered in the JavaDoc of the Pattern class.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that worked! If you could explain why that works and post it an answer, I will be happy to award this question to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `(.+)` to `(.+?)`, this is covered in the JavaDoc of the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class under "Reluctant quantifiers".

If we look at the [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html) we can read more about it under "Differences Among Greedy, Reluctant, and Possessive Quantifiers".

> The reluctant quantifiers, however, take the opposite approach: They start at the beginning of the input string, then reluctantly eat one character at a time looking for a match. The last thing they try is the entire input string.